# How to delete commit from the GIT?

Tags: git

```
MacBook-Pro:$ git log
commit 3d3232089a4a3683230b10865f1a3b2c59ecb5db
Author: ********
Date:   Thu Nov 20 13:25:56 2014 +0200

    view added

commit f59c3d655b9c4ab9b224af285b50e456d6e1d7f2
Author: ********
Date:   Thu Nov 20 13:23:50 2014 +0200

    lol

commit a4c52b4a543204cd182687df87ee1723adc02e92
Author: ********
Date:   Thu Nov 13 20:30:12 2014 +0200

    tmp
```

How to just remove commits from the GIT leave local code untouched? For example I want to delte `lol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure there are no changes hanging in working directory after the last commit. 
If there are some, stash them (`git stash`, after rewriting the commit history reapply the changes with `git stash apply`) or update the last commit with them (`git commit --am` is OK in most cases).

Then:

```
$ git rebase -i <commit-pointer>
```

Where commit pointer is the commit hash or `HEAD~[number]`. You're aiming for the commit BEFORE the one you want to clear. That will be the commit changes from `lol` are going to.

An editor (probably nano) will show up with a temporary file created by Git (`git-rebase-todo`).
Follow the instructions (you are going to change 'pick f59c3d6 lol' to 'fixup f59c3d6 lol') and save the file (Ctrl-X, y, Enter).

If you want to apply the changes from `lol` to the newer commit you will have to mark the `view added` commit with `squash` and after saving the `git-rebase-todo` file another one will pop out with commit messages of squashed commits. Edit it and save.

The complexity of changing a commit N commits ago is something like O(N) so better don't change something from the very beginning of the project or at least go have a coffee then.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want to do an interactive rebase. When you run this command, the editor will open, and you'll be able to see a list of commits, with their SHAs, the commit message, and the action to take on each commit. By default, they will all be "picked". We have 7 options for what to do with a commit: pick, squash, edit, reword, fixup, exec and delete. To delete you simply just need to remove the line, BUT you will also lose the code changes with it. Instead, we want to squash the commit, merging it into the commit that came before. Then, we can reword the commit message if necessary, and move on. It'll look something like this

```
git rebase --interactive --root master
#editor opens up
```

Your file will look something like this:

```
pick a4c52b4 tmp
pick f59c3d6 lol
pick 3d32320 view added
```

We need to change the second line to "remove" the `lol` commit:

```
pick a4c52b4 tmp
squash f59c3d6 lol
pick 3d32320 view added
```

Once we save and close the file, git will parse the file and rebase. At the squash, it'll open another editor window, allowing you to adjust the commit message if you want. If something goes horribly wrong, git will boot you to the command line. You can then run `git rebase --abort` and git should fix everything to its original state.

### A couple of notes

This rewrites your commit history. IF these commits are already pushed and shared, it's not worth the grief of force-pushing and telling everyone that you had to rewrite the history so they take appropriate measures. However, if your commits are local-only, or if the remote git repository is for your purpose only, it should be fine. You will have to run `git push --force` to tell git that things may not match the remote, and that it needs to just force the push.